# ESP8266 12E NodeMCU 1.0 pin mapping for micro sd card?

Tags: iot, sd-card, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I tried several pin conifguration to connect nodemcu and micro sd card. However, I had not any luck to successfully connect to sd card. I followed [esp8266 forum](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=3558#p20419) and some other solution! I need your suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pin mapping that SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:

- **MicroSD => ESP8266**
- MOSI(DI) -> D7 (GPIO13) HMOSI
- MISO(DO) -> D6 (GPIO12) HMISO
- CLK      -> D5 (GPIO14) HSCLK
- CS       -> D2 (GPIO4)
- VDD -> Vin/3V3
- GND -> GND

All other pin that available in microsd will not need to use!

After connecting all pin, you can test one of the example that given in by default. For example, In Arduino IDE you can use this example, ***File -> Examples -> 8266(SD) -> CardInfo***

Comment: Vin pin is > 3.3V, thats the voltage USB is providing actually... Please check it first with multimeter!

Answer (score 0):

CONNECT SDCARD NODEMCU - TESTED

```
CS   - D8
MISO - D7
MOSI - D6
SCK  - D5
```

[image: Fritzing breadboard]

In Arduino IDE open FILE > EXAMPLES > SD > CARDINFO

Change

```
const int chipSelect = 15; // original code is 4
```

That's it, your SD Card will be working.

This works, just tested on my breadboard.